# Best way to draw text in 3d space

Tags: libgdx

I have been developing a game in libgdx, which utilises cards with a number of stats on them. Originally I had done the game in 2d but decided to try itn out in 3d and have had some success so far. However, I cannot work out the best way to draw the text stats onto the cards. I have had no real luck with any of the approaches taken, I tried using a FBO to create the text over the texture and remapping the texture, but this didnt seem to work, and i tried drawing the text and then applying the same transformations from the cards to the text, but this too achieved nothing.
What would be the best approach to going about this, and where can I get guidance on how to execute this?

Comment: Good question since I'm pretty sure LibGDX has been discontinued for some time now.

Comment: @KaiQing It is still actively developed. If you look at the commit log for the project on Github, the owners are still making several commits a week. Not sure why version increases are so rare. But the owners also make the popular Spine tool, which is built with Libgdx so I don't expect an end to active development any time soon.

Comment: This kind of open-ended questions would be better served on the Libgdx site's forum.

Comment: Good to know. I always liked libGDX but I never completed a project with it. Got things going well for a while. Hope it picks back up.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is signed distance field rendering.

The LibGDX Wiki has an article on it [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).